# Accept incoming traffic from loadbalancer as ingress, but send traffic originating from host to default gateway

Tags: linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

### Setup

I have Linux virtual machines running on google cloud platform that are behind an [external TCP forwarding loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network).
The loadbalancer works by forwarding TCP traffic to healthy instances as-is (without modifying the IP addresses). To ensure traffic forwarded by the loadbalancer is accepted by the VMs, Googles guest-agent will by default add entries to the local routing table with the equivalent of this command:

```
ip route add to local LOADBALANCERIP/32 dev eth0 proto 66
```

### Current behavior

While this accomplishes the main goal of accepting forwarded traffic, it has one disadvantage: TCP connections originating from the targeted instances to the loadbalancer IP never leave the instance as the IP is in the local routing table.

### Wanted behavior

Is it possible (using routing, iptables or other means) to accept *incoming* TCP connections while also allowing *outgoing* traffic to go to the loadbalancer?

The reason I would want to do this is as follows:
Consider a service running on the targeted instances (kubernetes control plane in my case) that is targeted by the loadbalancer. There are also other programs running on the same instances which need to connect to a healthy instance of the service. For HA purposes, I would like to ensure that other programs running on the same instance can route traffic to healthy instances of the service. Using the current configuration, traffic for the main service will always be routed locally, even if the local service instance is unhealthy.

### Solutions evaluated

One solution I considered is using a proxy loadbalancer instead. This has other disadvantages (only allowing a narrow set of ports being the main problem).

Comment: Why would you connect from the targeted instances to the load balancer? Why do you want outgoing traffic to go to the loadbalancer?

Comment: One instance where the instance needs to connect out to the loadbalancer is this: The kubernetes apiserver should be running on the instances. To deploy kubernetes, I use `kubeadm join` to add additional control plane nodes. During the join process, kubeadm will attempt to connect to the control plane while the local host is not yet a healthy kubernetes node.

Comment: @Malt3 your issue resolved?

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu since a few days ago, Google allows using any port for proxy loadbalancers. So this is what I ended up using instead. The original issue still remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
ip route add to main LOADBALANCERIP/32 dev eth0 proto 66
```

Comment: Please provide additional details and context on your answer.